# Parsing a component of a regex followed by an optional quantifier character

Tags: beginner, parsing, haskell, regex, parsec

I have a piece of parsec code that parses a `unit` optionally followed by `?`, `+` or `*`. Depending on which type I build my Regex (this is a part of a regex parser) as follows:

```
factor = unit >>= (\x -> (try (char '?' >> return (Or Epsilon x))
                         <|> try (char '+' >> return (Then x (Star x)))
                         <|> try (char '*' >> return (Star x))
                         <|> return x))
```

This is ugly, so is the `do` version:

```
factor = do
    x <- unit
    (try (char '?' >> return (Or Epsilon x))    <|>
     try (char '+' >> return (Then x (Star x))) <|>
     try (char '*' >> return (Star x))          <|>
     return x)
```

Please help me make it simpler.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Whenever I find myself using a lambda, I usually replace it with a local definition:

```
factor = unit >>= factor'
 where
  factor' x
    =  try (char '?' >> return (Or Epsilon x))
   <|> try (char '+' >> return (Then x (Star x)))
   <|> try (char '*' >> return (Star x))
   <|> return x
```

Since you only need to look at one character to pick the right branch, you don't need to use `try` everywhere:

```
factor = unit >>= factor'
 where
  factor' x
    =  (char '?' >> return (Or Epsilon x))
   <|> (char '+' >> return (Then x (Star x)))
   <|> (char '*' >> return (Star x))
   <|> return x
```

Finally, we can get rid of the extra parens by using `*>` instead of `>>`, and we can replace `return` with `pure`:

```
factor = unit >>= factor'
 where
  factor' x
    =  char '?' *> pure (Or Epsilon x)
   <|> char '+' *> pure (Then x (Star x))
   <|> char '*' *> pure (Star x)
   <|> pure x
```

This works because `*>` has higher precedence than `<|>` which has higher precedence than `>>`.

I find this easier to read. We've restricted the bulk of our code to Applicative operations, and we only need to use Monadic bind at the beginning where `factor'` has a direct dependency on `unit`.

EDIT: We don't need `try` anymore because `char x` only consumes a character if the next character in the input stream matches `x`. Furthermore, each of your branches can either completely match or it can completely fail, and there's no danger of overlap between rules. As an example, here's a simple parser that, like yours, has simple match-or-fail parsers that consume only one character and do not overlap:

```
data Foo = One | Zero
  deriving (Eq, Show)

foo =  char '1' *> pure One
   <|> char '0' *> pure Zero
```

If we decide to add a new rule that does overlap, we'll have a problem:

```
data Foo = One | Zero | Ten
  deriving (Eq, Show)

foo =  char '1' *> pure One
   <|> char '0' *> pure Zero
   <|> char '1' *> char '0' *> pure Ten
```

Now our first and last rule overlap! We can never successfully parse a Ten:

```
> parse foo "" "1"
Right One
> parse foo "" "10"
Right One
```

One's first instinct might be to switch the order of the rules, but this just introduces a new problem:

```
foo =  char '1' *> char '0' *> pure Ten
   <|> char '0' *> pure Zero
   <|> char '1' *> pure One

> parse foo "" "10"
Right Ten
> parse foo "" "1"
Left (line 1, column 2):
unexpected end of input
expecting "0"
```

Since the first `char '1'` has already consumed a character, we've *committed* to that branch. This is the case where you want to use `try`; where you might need to backtrack after initially committing to some rule that consumes input:

```
foo =  try (char '1' *> char '0' *> pure Ten)
   <|> char '0' *> pure Zero
   <|> char '1' *> pure One

> parse foo "" "0"
Right Zero
> parse foo "" "1"
Right One
> parse foo "" "10"
Right Ten
```

Because many parsers are more complicated than `char`, it can be easy to just add `try` without thinking. This can make your parser less efficient because it may have to backtrack many times before it makes progress. It can be worth your time to investigate whether a `try` is really necessary.